# Movement of a slider's handle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I've come across a minor problem, maybe I'm messing out the syntax somehow, so if you see something like this, help me sort it out. So, here is the code:

```
 $('#slangle.ui-slider-handle').animate({'left':+20});
```

The idea is - something happens and it triggers a function containing the line of code you see above. I've checked whether the function is being triggered and it is triggered correctly. As I have 3 sliders, I'm trying to refer to the slider #slangle and to move its handle once by 20 pixels to the right but it remains static so far. Alternative solutions are also accepted, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little bit of syntax:

`$('#slangle.ui-slider-handle').animate({'left':'+=20px'});`

**UPDATE:**

It turned out that that problem was about [Slider Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-value) and getting and setting the handle of the slider.

Comment: I just used your original code and made it run. If you are using JQuery Mobile or similar framework, call the element you made in your code, not elements created by framework.

Comment: op, I recognized something, on initialization the slider is defined as $(#slangle).slider(something, something..) and I think that this .slider should be somehow implied in the line we're trying to bring to work. Ideas?

Comment: Use `$('#slangle').animate({'left':'+=20px'});` only to reffer to the element. More context of the code would be helpful, it looks like there is more to correct. Look again to https://jsfiddle.net/hemdrsqa/8/ .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88633/discussion-between-once-and-kdx2).

Comment: OK, so after a bit of mindstorming Once and I came up with a solution for this. 
` function gr(){`
    `var coefficient; // that's a coefficient of increment`
   `coefficient = $( "#selector" ).slider( "option", "value" );`
     `$( "#selector" ).slider('option','value',coefficient);`
     `$( "#selector" ).slider('option','value',coefficient + 10); `

we create a variable which at first checks the last value of the slider as in my case it could be adjusted and by mouse dragging. Later on we increase the coef with 10, it can be lower or more than 10 depending on the move-

Comment: -ment precision, the lesser the increment number, in our case 10 is, the slower but more precise slider's handle movement is and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<button id="button">
  Click here
</button>
<div id="div1" width="100" height="123"
     style="position: relative; left: 10px;">div content</div>

$( "#button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#div1" ).animate({
    left: "+=50"
  });
});
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bLt0rx3z/